# A column named "date" in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a query like this on sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT panel_pn_side, serial_nb, date, panel_stts
FROM  table
```

and problem is, it doesn't get that date is a column name, maybe because to it, date is a keyword and not a column. I get the following error :

```
ERROR: column "date" does not exist
```

Do you guys have a solution for me ? 
Thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. In standard SQL you would need double quotes: `"date"` (or possibly `"DATE"`)

Comment: `date` is a reserved word; put it as `"date"` (Oracle) or `[date]` (MS SQL)

Comment: When you used the tag [tag:sql], you were shown a large box that suggested you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, because there are differences between them. Why did you ignore that advice? Clearly it makes a difference, as you can see by the fact that a) **you were advised in advance that it did**, and b) **you don't have an answer, but instead a comment asking which DBMS you're using because they're different**. When you're asking a question, and those messages are shown to you, **don't ignore them**, because they have information you need.

Comment: Maybe a double-quoted case-sensitiv column name, can you show the table definition?

Comment: I didn't create this database, i'm using palantir which is something I don't master and I have no idea if it's mysql or oracle (i tried to find information but couldn't). Escaping with either backtick or double quote doesn't work.

Comment: @VincentBrisse If you do `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table` or `SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 1` (dbms-dependent), what columns do you see?  Are you *certain* that a column named `date` even exists?

Comment: @VincentBrisse Because of the text in the error message, I assume that it is PostgreSQL.

Comment: Write the code using a table alias:  `SELECT DISTINCT T.panel_pn_side, T.serial_nb, T.date, T.panel_stts
FROM  table AS T`  Does the name of the field autocomplete for you?

Comment: @Siyual I get   
    ERROR: syntax error at or near "1"Position: 12. ANd yea I'm certain a column named date exists.

Comment: @Zorkolot I get `ERROR: column t.date does not exist Position: 47`

Comment: Just want to add that for Cloudera it is ` `date` `

Answer (score 1):

Actually, even though it was shown as "date" in the database, after thorough research it appears that there were two columns, "date_timestampInUTC" and "date_originalTimezone" and that's why SQL didn't recognize the column named date. I have no idea what happened. Thank you all for the answers